# Is it possible to a pass function to an included file?

Tags: php

I have a view class with a function to build the view

```
class view {
   //...
     public function build() {
         $view = $this;            
         $data = $this->resources->data;

         function s($value) {
            return \classes\tools\html\html::specialChars($value);
         }

         require $this->viewFile;
     }
    //...
   }
```

And a view some view files

```
<?php var_dump($view);
// works fine, variables passed ok ?>

<?= s($data->someUnsafeString) ?> 
<?php //Fatal error: Call to undefined function s() ?>
```

I could define the function `s` In each view file but I really dont want to have to do that.

I could pass the function as a variable `$s=function(){..}` but I'd prefer not too

I could call the static function in the view directly but even that is more long winded than I'd like:

```
<?= html::s($data->someUnsafeString) ?>
```

Is this possible? or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your project has a `Front Controller` (one file - entry point),
then you can to declare your function in common namespace in this or required(`#require`) by this file.

Common namespace is code without namespace or

```
namespace {
  function s() {
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I was doing wrong, well spotted

Answer (score 4):

You may be misunderstanding what you're doing there. Functions aren't scoped in PHP. Your `function s(..)` inside `view::build` is merely declaring a regular **global** function. Doing that inside functions isn't anything special. You can simply declare functions conditionally in PHP, e.g.:

```
if (!function_exists('s')) {
    function s(..) ..
}
```

So just put that function declaration into a separate file and `include` it as needed; no need to define it again and again separately in each file.

Comment: Ok I figured it out now, the above would have worked, provided that my view file was in the same namespace as the view class. Very helpful thanks